# Pandas Data frame else option

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to figure out how I can get values to return one value if the column equals CA, NV, or HI. If it doesn't equal one of those, I want it to return a different value.

The first line works fine, but can't figure out how to get it to return .035 if it is not one of those states.

Thank you!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


repone.loc[(repone['State'] == 'CA') | (repone['State'] == 'NV') | (repone['State'] == 'HI'), 'Commission %'] = .07
repone.loc[(repone['State'] != 'CA') | (repone['State'] != 'NV') | (repone['State'] != 'HI'), 'Commission %'] = .035
```

Comment: Hint: the use of `|` in the second line is not what you want, per [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Answer (score 1):

Another good option for this might be `np.select` which would allow you to expand out if you decided to use other stats in the future.

```
condition_list = [repone['State'].isin(['CA', 'NV', 'HI'])]

choice_list = [.07]

repone['Commission %'] = np.select(condition_list, choice_list, .35)
```

This could be useful if you needed to add any additional state combinations. For this specific situation a 1 for 1 of `np.select` might not be ideal, but it is at least another option to put in your tool belt.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use `&` (and) instead of `|` (or) on the second line:

```
repone.loc[(repone['State'] == 'CA') | (repone['State'] == 'NV') | (repone['State'] == 'HI'), 'Commission %'] = .07
repone.loc[(repone['State'] != 'CA') & (repone['State'] != 'NV') & (repone['State'] != 'HI'), 'Commission %'] = .035
```

Or you can negate the first condition:

```
filter = (repone['State'] == 'CA') | (repone['State'] == 'NV') | (repone['State'] == 'HI')

repone.loc[filter, 'Commission %'] = .07
repone.loc[~filter, 'Commission %'] = .035
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use multiple conditions, go for [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html):

```
repone.loc[repone['State'].isin(['CA', 'NV', 'HI'], 'Commission %'] = .07
repone.loc[~repone['State'].isin(['CA', 'NV', 'HI'], 'Commission %'] = .035
```

Or:

```
mask = repone['State'].isin(['CA', 'NV', 'HI']
repone.loc[mask, 'Commission %'] = .07
repone.loc[~mask, 'Commission %'] = .035
```

Or, better, to change both possibilities in a single call, combine with [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
repone['Commission %'] = np.where(repone['State'].isin(['CA', 'NV', 'HI'],
                                  .07, .035)
```